# Bitbucket Repo Name vs URL

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

When creating a git repo on github if you name it "test--repo1" both the url and the repo name will contain the "--".

When creating a git repo on bitbucket if you name it "test--repo1" the repo will be named "test--repo1" but the url to that repo will only contain one "-" instead of "--" in the url.

How do I force bitbucket to keep "--" in both the repo name and the url that points to that repo?

Note: This happens with both the web interface and the api when creating repos with "--" in the name.

Comment: You need to ask BitBucket support about that one. Even a rename won't work...

Comment: I did encounter a similar thing recently. Is the '--' really that important? If it is then the only goto is the bitbucket support

Comment: It is important to us. I've opened and issue with bitbucket. You can upvote it here: [link](http://support.atlassian.com/browse/BBS-5114)